# Getting linting error - error Unexpected empty object pattern no-empty-pattern

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

I am getting this linting error for the below code- "error  Unexpected empty object pattern  no-empty-pattern". Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Its a tsx file.

```
const stateToProps = ({}, { data = [], filters = {}, staticFilters = 
  [{}] }) => {
  const allFilters = staticFilters ? Object.assign({}, filters, ...staticFilters) : filters;
  const newData = getFilteredRows(allFilters, data);
  return {
      data: newData,
      unfilteredData: data,
  };
};
//called like this
export const NodeList = connect<{}, {}, CustomNodeTableProps>(stateToProps)(CustomNodeTable);
```

Answer (score 21):

I ran this code through the [ESLint demo](https://eslint.org/demo) app after transpiling the TypeScript; the linter error is coming from `{}` in the first line.

```
const stateToProps = ({}, // rest of the function
```

[no-empty-pattern](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-empty-pattern) is meant to catch code that appears to be using destructuring, but does not assign any variables. In the code above, `stateToProps` accepts a first argument, but no matter what that argument is, it is destructured as an empty object `{}` and nothing is assigned.

If that first argument matters, you could change the code to descructure it:

```
const stateToProps = ({importantThing},
```

If not, indicate that we don't care:

```
const stateToProps = (_,
```

Or, set a default.

```
const stateToProps = (importantThing = {},
```

Each of these changes resolve the ESLint warning.

Comment: Exactly, what I need. Thanks @JakeWorth

Answer (score 3):

In no-empty-pattern situations like this I tend to disable the lint rule for that particular line by adding the following comment.

JavaScript:

```
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-empty-pattern
  const stateToProps = ({}, otherParams, // rest of the function
    ...
```

TypeScript:

```
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-pattern
  const stateToProps = ({}, otherParams, // rest of the function
    ...
```

The reasoning for this is first, that I DO NOT want turn off the no-empty-pattern globally, and second I also DO NOT want to collect plenty of lint warnings, as this would blur the important warnings and errors.